# php, from json decode to individual variables

Tags: php, json

I am trying to go from a cur request to a page with some info.

I have the curl working but I have trouble going from the decode json to individual php variables. the conten after json_decode is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["request"]=> string(20) "mailboxes/status/get" ["result"]=> string(1) "0" } ["status"]=> string(7) "success" }
```

I need the value of result which is 0 here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you can fly you need to start from the ground: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = $data->response->result;
```

Assuming the variable $data is where you stored your json_decode. It returns an instance of stdClass, and viewing the vardump, you can see the structure and get the data you want.